# Caption in longtblr does not work

Tags: errors, captions, tabularray, longtblr

Why do `\caption` and `\label` not work in the `longtblr` environment (see pictures)?
I can´t find anything specific in the caption documentation regarding longtables.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
toc=bibliography,
numbers=noendperiod
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
left=3cm,
right=2.5cm,
top=2.5cm,
bottom=2.0cm,
includehead,
includefoot
]{geometry}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{makecell}   

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\scriptsize}
\usepackage[font={normal}]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries\rmfamily}


\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{0.72\linewidth}
\usepackage[skip=10pt]{parskip}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}p{#1}}

\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[4cm][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \tocfill}}
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}
\raggedbottom
\singlespacing\label{key}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{landscape}
        \footnotesize
        \setlist[itemize]{nosep,leftmargin=*}
        \SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
        {\def\arraystretch{2}\tabcolsep=10pt
            \begin{longtblr}
                [
                \setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt}
                caption = {Characteristics of pressure driven membrane processes},
                entry = {Characteristics of pressure driven membrane processes},
                label = {tab:pressuredriven},
                ]{colspec = {@{} X[1,l] *{4}{X[l]} @{}},
                    stretch = -1, %<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                    % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
                    rowsep = 5pt,
                    rowhead  = 1,
                    measure = vbox,
                }
                \toprule
                &   A
                &   B 
                &   C
                &   D        \\
                \midrule    
                E&F&G&&I\\
                E&F&G&H&I\\
                E&F&G&H&I\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{longtblr}
        }
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: make a shorter example. There is certainly no need for all the lines or the landscape or all these packages etc. Shorter examples are much easier to debug.

Comment: Erh, why is the caption set twice? Once with the `longtblr` options and once with `\caption`, remove the latter.

Comment: sorry, now it´s the correct code. I also added a picture where you can see that the caption does not show.

Comment: You've got a stray `\setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt}` which is interpreted a part of a key, thus swallowing the key `caption`. Apparently the package ignores silently undefined keys. Strange choice.

Comment: thanks. deleting the 'stray' solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `tabularray` apparently silently ignores undefined keys, leading to meaningless output without warning. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[caption=foo,some nonsense]{colspec={ll}}
a & b
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

runs without issue but produces

[image]

A very questionable design choice in my opinion.

In your case, in the optional parameter to `longtblr` you have

```
\begin{longtblr}
                [
                \setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt}
                caption = {Characteristics of pressure driven membrane processes},
                % ...
                ]{...}
```

and the stray `\setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt}` is interpreted as part of the "key" `\setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt} caption`, which then does nothing (apparently) but to swallow the caption.